# questions regarding how many bytes each type is

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

I have questions about how many bytes each type might be.

Question 1) now()  timestamp. i think it's uint which means uint256 which means 32 bytes? Am I right?

Question 2) what does bytes32 mean? They say it's an array. but i can't do push on it. something like this: `bytes32 public array; array.push("good");` so it's kind of an array like a string? `string s = "good";` like this? but imagine what if I want to have arrays of 32 bytes?

Question 3) what about event logs topics? if I write `uint indexed var1` in a log, a) i know that it's gonna cost me 32 bytes as uint is 32 bytes but what if b) I write `bytes16 indexed var2` ,  is it still gonna cost me 32 bytes or just 16 bytes? and c) what if i save more than 32 bytes in a log and it's a topic, lets say 50bytes, is it gonna cost me still 32 bytes and keccak256 hash will be stored there ? Am I right in a) , b) and c)

Thanks guys. before writing questions, I always try to put my idea on it .

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1) now() timestamp. i think it's uint which means uint256 which means 32 bytes? Am I right?

[Yes, that is correct.](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties)

> Question 2) what does bytes32 mean? They say it's an array. but i can't do push on it. something like this: bytes32 public array; array.push("good"); so it's kind of an array like a string? string s = "good"; like this? but imagine what if I want to have arrays of 32 bytes?

[`bytes32` is just a 256 bit word.](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#fixed-size-byte-arrays) It's size is fixed, just like for example `uint256`. If you want a dynamically sized byte array, [use the `bytes` array type](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#dynamically-sized-byte-array)

> Question 3) what about event logs topics? if I write uint indexed var1 in a log, a) i know that it's gonna cost me 32 bytes as uint is 32 bytes but what if b) I write bytes16 indexed var2 , is it still gonna cost me 32 bytes or just 16 bytes? and c) what if i save more than 32 bytes in a log and it's a topic, lets say 50bytes, is it gonna cost me still 32 bytes and keccak256 hash will be stored there ? Am I right in a) , b) and c)

This is not very well documented. My advice is to test somehow it and possibly post the results here.

The [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) states that the logs can contain any amount of data on page 5 just before equation 24:

> A log entry is a tuple of the logger’s address possibly empty series of 32-byte log topics, and some number of bytes of data.